# Cordova - Android. Write file to directory which is accessible by normal user

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I am building a small application for android which needs to save a file to a directory which is accessible by a normal user. Said user should then be able to read those files.

I am using Cordova with the file system plugin.

Does anyone know how to write to a directory which is accessible by a normal user and not only by the Application it selfe? For eg. the Downloads directory.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has multiple options for saving files, i.e.

- internal storage: only accessible by your app.
- external storage: worldwide accessible. This is the best place for files that don't require access restrictions and for files that you want to share with other apps or allow the user to access with a computer.

For more details, see

- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage